# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar información al dar clic en un select?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un `select` con 4 `option`, al llenar todos los `option` muestra la información de una BD, quisiera que al volver a dar clic en un `select` la información se oculte, seleccione otro `option` y muestre la información de ese `option`, claro cada `select` ya trae su información.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#compania_input").click(function(){
     $("#idPeriodoTitulo").hide();
     $("#tabsHeader").hide();
     $("#tabsDetail").hide();
   });
});
```

He hecho esto, pero ya no me muestra información por que los campos están ocultos, es lo que se me ocurrió hacer, pero quisiera que se vieran dependiendo de la selección del `select`.

Espero me haya dado a entender.

Gracias!

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Answer (score 0):

Podrías adaptar este ejemplo a tus necesidades:

```js
// array de objetos con propiedades para las options
const $options = [
  { value: 'a', html: 'value a' },
  { value: 'b', html: 'value b' },
  { value: 'c', html: 'value c' },
  { value: 'd', html: 'value d' }
]

// target select
const $select = $('#my-select')

/**
 * inicialización del DOM cuando ha sido renderizado
 * 
 */
$(document).ready(function () {
  // agrega al select las options
  appendOptionsToSelect($options)

  // oculta la primera option porque viene seleccionada por defecto
  setOptionsToDisplay($options[0].value)

  // inicializa el listener del select cada vez que cambia de valor
  initSelectListener()
})

/**
 * limpia la propiedad display de todas las options y setea display: none
 * a la option con el value recibido 
 * 
 * @param {number} value 
 */
function setOptionsToDisplay(value) {
  $select.find('option').css('display', '')
  $select.find(`option[value="${value}"]`).css('display', 'none')
}

/**
 * recibe el array de options y las inserta en el select
 * 
 * @param {array} options 
 */
function appendOptionsToSelect(options) {
  let html = ''
  options.forEach(option =>
    html += `
          <option value="${option.value}">
            ${option.html}
          </option>
      `
  )
  $select.append(html)
}

/**
 * inicializa el listener para el select cada vez que cambie el valor de una option
 * 
 */
function initSelectListener() {
  $select.change(function () {
    setOptionsToDisplay(this.value)
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my-select">
    </select>
```